# ¿Por qué el valor de -1 se imprime en pantalla?

Tags: c

Mi duda (básica) es sobre un ejercicio del libro "aprendiendo C en 24 hs.".

En un ejercicio declara:

```c
signed char ch;
ch=0xFF;
//luego imprime abajo:
printf("El valor decimal de 0xFF es %d.\n", ch);
//resultado:
//El valor decimal de 0xFF es -1.
```

Y mi pregunta es, ¿de dónde sale ése -1? Por favor, a quien me responda que me lo explique fácil. Gracias

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En C, una variable de tipo `char` con signo tienen una capacidad máxima de números negativos y positivos que puede soportar dicha variable. En este caso una variable de tipo `signed char` solo puede guardar de `-128` a `127` números, si sobrepasas ese rango, ocurrirá un [desbordamiento numérico](https://es.qwe.wiki/wiki/Integer_overflow).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
int main(void)
{   
    signed char ch = 128;
    printf("%d\n", ch);

    return 0;   
}
```

En pantalla da como resultado: `-128` y esto se debe porque la variable `ch` solo puede guardar números positivos que estén en el rango de `0` a `127`, si se sobrepasa ese rango, el valor no será el deseado.

Respondiendo a la pregunta:

> > ¿De dónde sale ése -1?

Porque ocurrió un desbordamiento aritmético. La variable `ch` no es capaz de almacenar el número `255` porque **solo puede guardar números que estén en el rango de 0 a 127**.

Aquí dejo un código de prueba donde muestran todos los valores obtenidos por el desbordamiento:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    signed char ch = 127;
    int i = 0;
    while(ch != -1)
    {
        ++i;
        ch = ch + 1;
        printf("ch = 127 + %d = %d\n", i, ch);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

El código de arriba debería de mostrar en pantalla lo siguiente:

```c
ch = 127 + 1 = -128
ch = 127 + 2 = -127
ch = 127 + 3 = -126
...
...
...
ch = 127 + 128 = -1
```

**Fuente:**

- [C data types.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)
- [Desbordamiento de enteros.](https://es.qwe.wiki/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: Gracias, ya entiendo mejor con esta respuesta. Pero me surge otra pregunta; si tuviera: 
main(){

   
    signed char ch = -124;
    printf("0X%X\n", ch);

    return 0;   
}              ¿hay alguna forma de predecir o deducir lógicamente el resultado en hex antes de ver el resultado que me da el compilador?

Comment: @DiegoSD Sí se puede. Debes usar un sistema numeración, en este caso, una conversión de decimal a hexadecimal. Como el decimal es un número negativo, pues el enfoque es diferente, sin embargo, una forma de convertirlo a hex, es convertir el decimal (sin el signo positvo) a binario y luego sacar su complemento a dos y a ese resultado agruparlo en grupos de 4 bits y después a cada grupo de bits lo conviertes a hexadecimal (básicamente sería una conversión de base 2 a 16). Aquí puedes mirar un enlace: [decimal a hexadecimal](https://www.calculadoraconversor.com/decimal-a-hexadecimal/).

Comment: @DiegoSD Otro enlace: [decimal negativo a binario](https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/conversion/convertir-decimal-negativo-binario/958677992/).

Answer (score -1):

Te explico primero, vamos a ir por partes:

El valor en hexadecimal `0xFF` si lo pasas a decimal es `255`, ¿Pero de donde sale el -1?, esto sale del primero número del binario que es `1`. Es decir  la conversión a binario es `11111111`.

**Decimal del complemento de 2 firmado**
Aquí es cuando tienes el valor -1
Esto significa que cuando tu representas los números binarios firmados son  `0` o `1`. pero también tienen valores positivo y  negativo `+` o `-`.

Por lo tanto entendemos que cuando el bit de signo es `0`, esto significa que el número tiene un valor positivo. Pero si el bit es `1`, entonces el número es negativo en valor.

Al ser todos `11111111` el valor sería negativo por lo tanto el resultado es `-1`.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: ¿Por qué el punto negativo? @DiegoSD

Comment: La votacion es secreta. Es imposible saber quien te califico negativo o porque. No esta bien acusar a alguien de algo asi.

Comment: disculpa pero sigo confundico, es decir, sé que el bit de signo indica si es positivo o negativo (0 o 1), pero que valga 1 es porque el resto de bits son todos 1? Esa parte no la entiendo. Además, si el char tuviera el valor por ej de 0x7F q a binario es 1111111 el resultado que me da es 127 y todos los bits son 1!....no, sigo sin entender....disculpa que abuse de tu generosidad y paciencia.

Answer (score -1):

0xFF es un entero hexadecimal que es 255 en decimal

en palabras simple lo que hacer el programa es guarda en la variable ch el valor de 255, entonces al guardar un integer en la variable char sin signo con la ayuda del valor ASCII. este valor se convertiría según la conversión ASCII en el valor de -1;